# Inserting and correctly scaling PGF figure made with matplotlib

Tags: tikz-pgf, beamer, matplotlib

I created a plot in matplotlib and saved it as a PGF file.

I insert the figure into Latex with the following:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \input{test_fig.pgf}
\end{figure}
```

With `\usepackage{pgf}` in the preamble.

The figure is then inserted but its to big, i.e. stretching far off the page.

I should mention that this is in a beamer document class.

Is there a method to scale the figure so that its as wide as the `\textwidth`?

I have tried inserting the figure with `\includegraphics[width=\textwidth]{test_fig.pgf}`, but I get the error `Unknown graphics extension: .pgf.`

Here is a MWE, with the PGF figure attached [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ft868jhgvdaaa5/test_fig.pgf?dl=0):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{beamerthemeshadow}
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}
\title{Slide Title}  
\author{Author}
\date{\today}
\frame{\titlepage} 
\section{Section 1} 
\frame{\frametitle{Title}
\begin{figure}
    \centering
    \resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{\input{test_fig.pgf}}
\end{figure}
}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Does `\resizebox{0.8\textwidth}{!}{\input{test_fig.pgf}}` give you the right control? [Scale .pgf image but preserve font size](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/148296/scale-pgf-image-but-preserve-font-size) may be of use.

Comment: Set the size in `matplotlib` before/when saving. E.g. `fig,ax=plt.subplots(figsize=(4,3))`, which will make the figure 4 inches wide and 3 inches tall.

Comment: @DaiBowen, indeed it does, but now the text size on the figure doesn't match the document font size anymore, which is kind of the reason why I want to use PGF.

Comment: What about the answer in the question I link to? http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/218134/

Comment: Seems a bit too complicated for me @DaiBowen. I will have to spend some time trying to figure that out.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. I would like a more automatic way. I don't want to have to think about the figure size every time I make a plot in matplotlib. For example I would like to use the same code whether I'm using beamer or a normal doc.

Comment: If you're able to post a compilable MWE with the `matplotlib` output you wish to work with this might make it easier for others to experiment and investigate in the mean time.

Comment: I can see that, though I personally do just that, in order to avoid having to scale figures. What you could do is set edit your `matplotlibrc` file and set  `figure.figsize` to around 4 in x 3 in (it's 8x6 by default).  The `\textwidth` in your `beamer` example is about 10.8cm, and in a default `article` it is 12.2cm, so a 10cm wide figure would fit reasonably well in both cases. You could also have a look at [`matplotlib2tikz`](https://github.com/nschloe/matplotlib2tikz), which generates `pgfplots` code that is higher level and easier to modify.

Comment: @TorbjørnT. Is `tikzscale` usable here? (I've never used it - just seem other people use it in somewhat-possibly-similar cases.)

Comment: @cfr I don't think so, though I haven't tried. I seem to remember another question where someone tried and failed to use `tikzscale`, I don't think it's made for the low-level `pgf` code the `pgf` backend creates. On the other hand, it would work with the output from `matplotlib2tikz` (from the same author as `matlab2tikz`).

Comment: I used matplotlib2tikz and I think its the best workflow. And you can set it so that you can set the figure size in Latex, making it super easy to scale the figure. I will post an answer to my question with a step-by-step guide on how to do this.

Comment: @Jonny do you still plan to produce such an answer?  Otherwise I think this might as well be marked a duplicate of [Scale .pgf image but preserve font size](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/148296/106162) or [Set the size of pgf picture?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/117042/106162)

Comment: @DaiBowen, I didn't get around to it and you are right, there is enough comonality. If you want you can mark it as a duplicate.