# Putting two pgf images beside each other

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphics

I have exported several images using `matplotlib` into `.pgf` files but I am having trouble organizing them together in my latex document. This is the best I can get:

```
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{cc}
 \input{toy_gauss.pgf}
 &
 \input{toy_gauss2.pgf}
\end{tabular}
\label{Fig:gauss}
\end{center}
```

But this yields one image too big causing the other to be caught off:
[image]

Also I tried using `\figure` env for this type of graphic and they throw errors so that's why I am using tabular here. I really just want two pgf images beside each other. (maybe even having four images in a 2x2 formation but one step at a time.)

Comment: Why not try using `\resizebox{\textwidth}{!}{\hbox{\input{a.pgf}\input{b.pgf}}}` instead of using a tabular environment?

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Set the size of pgf picture?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/117048/)

Comment: Your problem is that the figures are too large, set the size in matplotlib before saving as pgf.

Comment: @domperor Your solution worked the best. Anyway to add (a) and (b) automatically beside the figures? So you can refer to them as figure 3-b or figure 2-a?

Comment: Usually if you really want the automatic, you would need to write some macros; this comment space is too narrow for them (maybe it would be better for u asking this as another question). But the difficulty depends on the class you are using....

Answer (score 2):

Use one figure environ for both inputs  -- https://latex.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=32239

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{pgf}

\begin{document}

Some words..
\begin{figure}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \scalebox{0.45}{\input{figure1.pgf}}
        \label{Figure1}
        \caption{This is caption for Figure 1.}
    \end{minipage}
    \begin{minipage}[t]{0.5\linewidth}
        \centering
        \scalebox{0.45}{\input{figure2.pgf}}
        \label{Figure2}
        \caption{This is caption for Figure 2.}
    \end{minipage}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

Comment: As mentioned, the `figure` env doesn't work for me so I cannot test your solution.

Comment: @guy For the support of js bibra's answer.... Popular LaTeX document classes (e.g. article, book,... ) contain the `figure` environment. What kind of class are you using? Maybe it is better for u to give a minimum working example that begins with `\documentclass{...}` and end with `\end{document}`. This would make it easy for the community to help you in a precise way.

Comment: @guy How to make a “minimum working example”: https://www.texfaq.org/FAQ-minxampl